# How to install additional packages to jython jar in jmeter?

Tags: selenium, jar, jmeter, jython, jsr223

I am using jython inside jmeter by placing the jython.jar under "lib" folder of your JMeter installation. It runs successfully.

But the problem is I can't install additional packages or modules of python inside it. To be more specific, I want to run selenium in python inside jmeter, so needs selenium module needs to be installed in jython.

How should I do it?

Comment: Doesn't using regular method (`pip install selenium`) work? It should.

Comment: From where I should run the `pip` command. If I run normally, it will install selenium on my cpython2.7.10 (which is the deafault python).

Answer (score 2):

You can install Jython packages normally, i.e. using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), however make sure you are executing `pip` which comes with Jython (located under "bin" folder of your Jython installation)

1. Download [Jython installer](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) and perform the installation somewhere, i.e. `/temp/jython`
2. Navigate to `/temp/jython/bin` folder and execute `./pip install selenium` command
3. Add the next line to *user.properties* file which is located in JMeter's "bin" folder:

   ```
   user.classpath=/temp/jython;/temp/jython/javalib
   ```

   Note that JMeter restart will be required to pick the classpath up, check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information.
4. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and selenium `jython` from the "Language" dropdown
5. Add the next lines at the beginning of your script:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append('/temp/jython/Lib')
   sys.path.append('/temp/jython/Lib/site-packages')
   import selenium
   ```

You should be good to go.

Comment: Can't produce #4 here. Till #2, everything is successful, as I can import selenium from jython. May be the problem is in #3, can you please check it a bit?  Can it be any permission related issue? Though I could produce jython in dropdown placing jython-standalone.jar in lib of jmeter earlier.

Comment: Double check the path and restart JMeter after property change

Comment: Actually there was a OS related issue, may be you are working in a windows machine, where `;` is used as path separator in  `user.classpath`, whereas in linux, I had to use `:` as path separator. This is also described in comments of `user.properties` file. You can consider adding it to your answer to make it more complete one.